# postgres, change data field type of a table

Tags: database

I am using postgres and I have a table with a column whose data type is timestamp without time zone.

I would like to change the data type to bigint.  I am trying to store number of seconds since 1970 in the column.. so something big like 1397597908756

when I store this number in my table, it throws an exception "invalid input syntax for type timestamp: 1397597908756

So I tried to change the datatype from 'timestamp without timezone" to "bigint".  I did ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname SET DATA TYPE bigint USING updated::bigint;

I got the following error:
ERROR:  cannot cast type timestamp without time zone to bigint

Answer (score 0):

> ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname TYPE bigint USING
>   extract(epoch from columnname);

should do what you requested